# Why RxJava Observable.doOnDispose could trigger twice?

Tags: java, kotlin, observable, rx-java

This code

```
@RunWith(JUnit4::class)
class Playground {

    @Test
    fun test() {
        val subject1 = BehaviorSubject.create<Int>()
        val subject2 = BehaviorSubject.create<Int>()
        val observable = subject1.doOnDispose { println("subject1 observable disposed") }
        val disposable = Observable.combineLatest(
            observable.takeUntil { it < 1 },
            subject2.doOnDispose { println("subject2 observable disposed") },
            BiFunction { t1: Int, t2: Int ->
                println("$t1 $t2")
            })
            .subscribe()
        subject1.onNext(1)
        subject2.onNext(0)
        subject1.onNext(0)
        Thread.sleep(100)
        disposable.dispose()
    }
}
```

Have such output

```
1 0
0 0
subject1 observable disposed
subject1 observable disposed
subject2 observable disposed
```

Which is think wrong because it's strange that observable could be disposed twice. Can someone please explain why is it so?

```
implementation("io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.2")
```

Comment: I just ran your code it fired once only. Are you trying just to run this code snippet or you have any other logic involved. If yes, please expand your question a little, sometimes the problem is hidden in implementation. But in any case, it shouldn't fire twice AFAIK.

Comment: @Farid  I edited question code to make it more obvious, but yes, it's only code. 
Maybe it's due to concurrency so I changed code a little bit.

Comment: Okay, found the problem change your RxJava version to `implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.6'` that solved the problem. Check if it works for you? Apparently, this is was in the issue list for version 2.2.2, you can see the PR here https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/pull/6269

Comment: @Farid you right, maybe post it as answer?

Comment: Great, at least, we got it right )). Yeah, no problem adding it as an asnwer

Answer (score 1):

Since it worked for OP, wouldn't hurt to make it answer for future readers, I guess. Basically upgrading RxJava version to 2.2.6 resolves the problem:

```
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.6'
```

Anyone interested in the problem behind this behavior can check out the PR for the issue in RxJava 2.2.2 here https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/pull/6269